# Javascript get the items grouped in a single item

Tags: javascript

I have the following array

```
var data = [
      {material:1, item:'A'}
      {material:2, item:'B'}
       {material:1, item:'C'}
      {material:1, item:'D'}
  ]
```

What am looking forward is to get what materials are in this object of arrays

So I expect the final solution to be an array with just 1 and 2

```
var materials = [1,2]
```

So curently am stuck here

```
data.forEach((item)=>{
    //here am stuck on how to proceed
 })
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ES6 you can make use of a Set.

```
var materials = new Set(data.map(d => d.material));
```

You can easily turn that set back into an array if you wish.

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` into a `Set`, and then turn the set back into an array. Also note that you need to fix the syntax for your `data` - array items need to be separated with *commas*:

```js
var data=[{material:1,item:'A'},
{material:2,item:'B'},
{material:1,item:'C'},
{material:1,item:'D'}];

const set = data.reduce((set, { material }) => set.add(material), new Set());
console.log([...set]);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do is this:

```js
var data = [{
  material: 1,
  item: 'A'
}, {
  material: 2,
  item: 'B'
}, {
  material: 1,
  item: 'C'
}, {
  material: 1,
  item: 'D'
}]

var materials = [];

data.forEach(function(elem) {
  var material = elem.material;
  if (materials.includes(material)) {} else {
    materials.push(material);
  }
})
console.log(materials)
```

Please tell me if you need any clarification of what is happening.

Comment: Fixed, better now?

Comment: don't know how the includes work can you add a snippet please?

Comment: includes is from MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has already pointed out the obvious answer of using a `Set`. Here's an arguably more flexible way to do it.

```
const data = [
  { material:1, item:'A' },
  { material:2, item:'B' },
  { material:1, item:'C' },
  { material:1, item:'D' }
]

const map = data.reduce((acc, { material, item }) => {
  acc[material] = material in acc
    ? [ ...acc[material], item ]
    : [ item ]

  return acc
}, {})

// materials and items made of that material
console.log(map) // { 1: [ 'A', 'C', 'D' ], 2: [ 'B' ] }

// unique materials
console.log(Object.keys(map)) // [ '1', '2' ]
```

This would have a performance boost in the long run if you need to do more operations like find all materials made of X element. Instead of filtering you just do `data[material]`